# Java JPA Queries

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, mysql-error-1064

i'm trying to select all enteties from a databse where a certain date is older than 7 days. It works fine via SQLyog, but in Java it always throws this error:

```
[33, 76] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
[76, 101] The query contains a malformed ending.
```

This is my query in Java:

```
SELECT a FROM Applicants a WHERE (a.lastMod <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY a.applDate ASC
```

May the problem be the "CURRENT_DATE"-part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CURRENT_DATE` is ok, but `INTERVAL 7 DAY` is not a valid JPQL expression. You'll need to supply the date as parameter

```
WHERE a.lastMod <= :dateParam
```

Example:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Applicants a WHERE a.lastMod <= :dateParam ORDER BY a.applDate ASC");
q.setParameter("dateParam", dateParam);
List<Applicants> applicants = (List<Applicants>)q.getResultList();

// or, to avoid casting (thanks to @DavidSN)

TypedQuery<Applicants> q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Applicants a WHERE a.lastMod <= :dateParam ORDER BY a.applDate ASC", Applicants.class);
q.setParameter("dateParam", dateParam);
List<Applicants> applicants = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: I never worked with parameters. Can you please supply an example?

Comment: The example produces a unchecked cast warning. You have the option to use the typesafe version of the `createQuery` method: `TypedQuery<Applicants> q = em.createQuery("select ...", Applicants.class);` and gets the results without the List<Applicants> cast: `List<Applicants> applicants = q.getResultList();`

Answer (score 0):

```
EntityManager em = ...
Query q = em.createQuery ("SELECT a FROM Applicants a WHERE a.lastMod <= :dateParam");
q.setParameter("dateParam" , dateParam);
List<blabla> results = q.getResultList ();
```